# Shouldn't the minimum Succah size be 6x7 Tfachim?

Tags: shiurim-measurements, sukkah

According to [Bartenura on Mishna Sukkah 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bartenura_on_Mishnah_Sukkah.1.1.4?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi), the calculation for the minimum Succah footage is the footage one man occupies (1 Ama x 1 Ama), i.g. 6 by 6 Tfachim and 1 Tefach for his table:

> שהסוכה צריכה שתהא ז׳ על ז׳ כדי שתהא מחזקת ראשו ורובו ושולחנו,
>   ו׳ על ו׳ לראשו ורובו, וטפח על טפח לשולחנו:

But the table is not added on two adjacent walls, only one, so the final size should be 6x7 Tfachim.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: I thought we had this question already, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 3):

[Sha'ar HaTziyun 634:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=197) presents three answers:

1. Ma'amar Mordechai - he and his table need to be able to fit in the *sukkah* in any orientation.
2. Magen Avraham in the name of Rashi - they would eat lying down, so they would need the full seven by seven to fit (including the table).
3. Ran - an area smaller than seven by seven is too small to be considered a genuine living space.

Comment: For 1, wouldn't that imply a circle?

Comment: For 3, then what about Beit Hillel who allow 6x6? And if they're arguing whats a genuine space, why talk about tables?